Serverless SignalR in Azure Function: Call to InvokeAsync hangs after successful StartAsync
I'm trying to setup an Azure Function with a simple serverless hub I will use to notify web clients. The FunctionApp contains both the serverlesshub (named MyHub below) as well as a client (which will ultimately receive EgentGrid events and notify clients via MyHub).
After a successful StartAsync on the client, it hangs when calling InvokeAsync. Any clue what the issue might be?
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.SignalRService;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Net;

new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // not sure if this should be used or not. It doesn't seem to make a difference.
        //services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(); 

        services.AddServerlessHub<MyHub>();
        services.AddSingleton<Client>();
    })
    .Build()
    .Run();

public class Client
{
    private readonly HubConnection _connection;

    public Client()
    {
        string? hostname = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");

        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl($"http://{hostname}/api")
            .Build();

        _connection.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    [Function("test")]
    public async Task Negotiate([HttpTrigger] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        await _connection.InvokeAsync("broadcast", req.ToString());
    }
}

[SignalRConnection("AzureSignalRConnectionString")]
public class MyHub : ServerlessHub
{
    private const string HubName = nameof(MyHub);

    public MyHub(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
    }

    [Function("negotiate")]
    public static HttpResponseData Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequestData req,
        [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = HubName)] string connectionInfo)
    {
        HttpResponseData response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        response.WriteString(connectionInfo);
        return response;
    }

    [Function("broadcast")]
    public Task Broadcast(
        [SignalRTrigger(HubName, "messages", "broadcast", "message")] SignalRInvocationContext invocationContext,
        string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync(message);
    }
}

Note: If relevant, I have local.settings.json set to:
{
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "http://localhost:5002",
    "CORSCredentials": true
  },
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Trace"
    }
  },
  "Values": {
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "Endpoint=https://xxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=xxx;Version=1.0;",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}


Found the answer to my own question. I needed to configure an upstream as described in https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/BidirectionChat, though In my case, I didn't need to provide the code parameter, i.e. the URL I used is https://xxx.ngrok-free.app/runtime/webhooks/signalr.
